# wordpress unnecessary queries slow down server

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I checked in my server log, and realized that some operations in the database are overloading the server. However, in no time I make these operations, who makes is own wordpress.

The problem is I can not figure out why these operations are being done. They are like these (are cut off because the server gave me just that):

```
INSERT INTO `al_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('rewrite_rules',

DELETE FROM al_options WHERE option_name = 'rewrite_rules'
```

Sorry for bad english

Comment: there are not 'unnecessary' queries done by WordPress. and how low is the performance of the server ?. Maybe is some plugin/theme ?

Comment: is a theme created by myself. the plugins I use are these: admin menu editor, advanced custom fields, advanced custom fields(date and time picker), Capability Manager Enhanced, Comment Moderation E-mail to Post Author, press permit core, TinyMCE Advanced. wordpress seo(by yoast), WP-Mail-SMTP.